# Is it possible to handle non-primitive types in a variadic function?

Tags: c++, variables, variadic-functions

I have 2 versions of the same variadic function, however one works the other doesn't. I suspect the reason is because one is using a primitive type where the other uses std::string.

```
void test1(int f_num, ...)
{
    va_list file_names;
    va_start(file_names, f_num);

    for(int i=0; i<f_num; i++)
    {
        string name = string(va_arg(file_names, char*));
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    va_end(file_names);
}

void test2(int f_num, ...)
{
    va_list file_names;
    va_start(file_names, f_num);

    for(int i=0; i<f_num; i++)
    {
        string name = va_arg(file_names, string);
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    va_end(file_names);
}

int main()
{
    test1(3, "Hallo", "you", "people");
    test2(3, "Hallo", "you", "people");
}
```

The above results in the following output:

```
Hallo
you
people
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The first function thus works but the second doesn't. Am I correct to assume that it's because the variadic macro doesn't handle non-primitive types? Can you make it handle non-porimitive types?

Comment: You are not passing `std::string` objects to `test2()` so using `va_arg(..., string)` is wrong.  You need to use `char*` since that is what you are actually passing to the function.  Also, you don't need the extra type-cast on `string name = string(va_arg(file_names, char*))`, as `std::string` has a constructor and `operator=` that accept `char*` as input: `string name = va_arg(file_names, char*);` or `string name(va_arg(file_names, char*));`

Comment: Just use a variadic template.

Comment: As Henri suggests, with a variadic template this can be as simple as `((std::cout << args << '\n'), ...);` in C++17.

Comment: At least post what you think are the relevant header files in your code/

Comment: I would have expected this to be a duplicate, but actually all similar questions appear to predate C++11 and thus variadic templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `va_arg` decodes the `va_list`

You cannot use `va_arg` to convert the passed in variable argument parameter in a single go. The syntax of `va_arg` would be to decode the variable argument to match the type that was passed in. For example, if you pass in an `int` value, you must decode it as an `int` with `va_arg`. You cause undefined behavior if you try to decode it as anything else (like, as a `double`).

Since you passed in a string literal, the type should be `const char *`.

```
const char *arg = va_arg(file_names, const char *);
```

#### `va_arg` on non-trivial classes is implementation-defined

As [MSalter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847752/315052) clearly explains, even if you really passed in a `std::string` to a function expecting variable arguments, it is not necessarily going to work because the semantics are implementation-defined.

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg (18.10). … Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type (Clause 9) having a non- trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move contructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics. …
> <sub>C++.11 §[expr.call] ¶7</sub>

<sub>Note: (18.10) defines `va_arg`, and (Clause 9) is §[class].</sub>

#### Just use a variadic template

You can use C++11's variadic template argument feature to achieve the effect you want in a type safe way. Assume you actually want to do a little more than print each argument, the usual pattern is to recursively traverse the parameter pack, unpacking one parameter at a time.

```
void test3 (int f_num, std::string file_name) {
    std::cout << f_num << ':' << file_name << std::endl;
}

template <typename... T>
void test3 (int f_num, std::string file_name, T...rest) {
    test3(f_num, file_name);
    test3(f_num, rest...);
}
```

Thus, iteration is achieved by recursively calling the function, reducing the parameter pack by one parameter on the next recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first part is that you're mostly correct. There are restrictions on the use of class types, in particular if they have a non-trivial copy constructor (which `std::string` has). It might work on some implementations and not on others. Formally, that's *conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics*.

The second part is a bit harder, but also a bit simpler. These varargs are old C, and not typesafe. C++ does have typesafe variadics, via templates:

```
template<typename... T>
void test1(T... args)
{
    std::cout << ... << args << std::endl;
}
```

The problem  is that you need to know how to unpack those `args...` - they're called [*parameter packs*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). There are a few different ways to unpack them; this particular form is called a fold expression.

Comment: I am confused, I am attempting to compile the example you gave so I copy pasted your function without modification, the compiler however returns the error:
`error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<<’ token
     std::cout << ... << args << std::endl;`

Comment: It should be `(std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;`.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to ellaborate a bit more on how to iterate through the parameter list using variadic templates? I am reading the documentation but the synax is nto too clear to me

Comment: @miradulo: On closer inspection, I think the idea is to have a newline after each argument. Of course that shouldn't be a `std::endl` as there's no need to flush. I'll need to get back to that.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first impression as well. I left an idea for one way to get the newlines in the comments under the question, but I am sure there are many others as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you call test2 as such, it should work:

```
test2(3, std::string("Hallo"), std::string("you"), std::string("people"));
```

What's happening here is that when you pass "Hallo" you're passing a char*, not an std::string, so when you try to retrieve the char* by giving it a type of std::string with va_arg, it fails since the object isn't an std::string.

<s>Also, in some compilers, it seems that you can't pass types that aren't trivially destructable, when I tried this in cpp.sh it gave the error</s>

```
In function 'void test2(int, ...)':
27:23: error: cannot receive objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'; 
 In function 'int main()':
36:51: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'
```

Although it seems this isn't part of the standard as I couldn't find anywhere that required this, so I assume it's just a limitation of the compiler they're using. If anyone knows the details about this, I'll edit the answer with the correct information.

<s>Like Henri Menke said, it seems the problem is that cpp.sh is using an old version that isn't c++11 compliant, so if you use a compiler that is at least c++11 compliant, you can use std::string within variadic arguments.</s>

It appears this is an implementation detail, as miradulo said, so it will depend on your compiler, and not the standard version you're using.

And also, like Henri Menke mentioned, if you use

```
using std::string_literals;
```

And then put an 's' at the end of the normal string as such:

`test2(3, "Hallo"s, "you"s, "people"s);`

It transforms the char* to a std::string so you can use them like this to call test2, this is due to [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s).

Comment: `test2(3, "Hallo"s, "you"s, "people"s);` is much more compact (needs `using namespace std::string_literals;`).

Comment: The fact that it does not compile on http://cpp.sh/ is because they are using an ancient compiler (GCC 4.9) which is not even fully C++11-compatible.  I recommend https://wandbox.org/ instead.

Comment: It isn't true that C++11 compliant compilers will allow non-trivially constructible types like `std::string` in variadic arguments. It is only conditionally supported with implementation defined semantics, as MSalters mentions. For instance, Clang 6 won't compile this as well.